# What does this PHP code stand for: '<<<INPUT INPUT'?

Tags: php, string

I found this code at Zend's page ...

```
<?php
$input = <<<INPUT
some text
INPUT;
?>
```

It seems to be the same like ...

```
<?php
$input = 'some text';
?>
```

I've never seen that before and can't find anything about it. Can someone give me a keyword?

(see: framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.escaper.escaping-javascript.html)

ty

Comment: The closing herdoc literal is incorrectly indented in your example, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple heredoc syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

A quote from the manual:

A string literal can be specified in four different ways:

- single quoted
- double quoted
- heredoc syntax
- nowdoc syntax (since PHP 5.3.0)

heredoc would as you have it:

```
$input = <<<INPUT
    some text
INPUT;
```

And pretty similar to that would be nowdoc:

```
$input = <<<'INPUT'
          //^     ^ See here the difference
    some text
INPUT;
```

Comment: fast, faster, stackoverflow. thx @all!

Answer (score 1):

Using the three less thans and a TAG is for multi-line strings.  You end the multi-line string with the same TAG you chose at the beginning.  In your case, the TAG is "INPUT".